# Length of columns excluding NA in r

Tags: r

Suppose that I have a `data.frame` as follows:

```
   a  b c
1  5 NA 6
2 NA NA 7
3  6  5 8
```

I would like to find the length of each column, excluding NA's. The answer should look like

```
a b c 
2 1 3
```

So far, I've tried:

```
 !is.na()                  # Gives TRUE/FALSE
 length(!is.na())          # 9 -> Length of the whole matrix
 dim(!is.na())             # 3 x 3 -> dimension of a matrix
 na.omit()                 # removes rows with any NA in it.
```

Please tell me how can I get the required answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Or faster :

```
colSums(!is.na(dat))
a b c 
2 1 3
```

Answer (score 5):

Though the sum is probably a faster solution, I think that `length(x[!is.na(x)])` is more readable.

Answer (score 3):

```
> apply(dat, 2, function(x){sum(!is.na(x))})
a b c 
2 1 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried NCOL instead of ncol and it worked.

```
> nrow(tsa$Region)
NULL
> NROW(tsa$Region)
[1] 27457


> ncol(tsa$Region)
NULL
> NCOL(tsa$Region)
[1] 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna count **non-NA values** in the entire data frame, the following will help.

```
 sum(!is.na(df))
[1] 3
```

then count non-NA values in each column as follows

```
colSums(!is.na(df))
a b c 
2 1 3
```