# Length of grouped columns, excluding NAs

Tags: r

How do I find the length of grouped columns, excluding NAs?

For example, with the following data frame,

```
Year  State var1  var2
TX    2     NA
WA    0     3
CA    NA    1
CA    2     NA
CA    2     3
TX    NA    4
WA    NA    NA
WA    3     3
CA    NA    0
```

I want it to return

```
State var1  var2
TX    1     1
WA    2     2
CA    2     3
```

Some similar questions have been asked (e.g. [R - Get number of values per group without counting NAs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32251996/r-get-number-of-values-per-group-without-counting-nas)) but I'm still struggling to get the output I want.

I've tried several variations on `summarise_if` and `summarise_all`, but they either throw up errors or don't calculate the right thing.

```
counts <- df %>%
group_by(State) %>% 
summarise_all(funs(length(!is.na(.))))
```

Comment: `sum(!is.na(x))`

Answer (score 1):

Just create an anonymous function that returns the sum of the logical vector returned by `is.na()`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(State) %>% 
  summarise_all(.funs = function(x) { sum(!is.na(x)) })

# A tibble: 3 x 3
   State  var1  var2
  <fctr> <int> <int>
1     CA     2     3
2     TX     1     1
3     WA     2     2
```

Answer (score 1):

With data.table:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[,lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(!is.na(x))),State]

   State var1 var2
1:    TX    1    1
2:    WA    2    2
3:    CA    2    3
```

Answer (score 0):

the dplyr approach:

```
df=tibble(State,var1,var2)%>%group_by(State)%>%summarize(var1=sum(!is.na(var1)),var2=sum(!is.na(var2)))
> df
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  State  var1  var2
  <chr> <int> <int>
1 CA        2     3
2 TX        1     1
3 WA        2     2
```